# Need to force hostname update without restart

Tags: centos, prompt, hostname

I need to change the hostname of a system without rebooting it. Im running CentOS 7 and have the correct hostname in the /etc/hostname file but im still showing the old hostname at prompt. I know that when I reboot the system it will check the hostname file and apply it, but is there anyway for me to update that without rebooting? Here is some info from the command line:

```
[root@gandalf sysconfig]# cat network
NETWORKING=yes
GATEWAY=192.168.80.1
HOSTNAME="sauron.domain.com"
[root@gandalf sysconfig]# cd ..
[root@gandalf etc]# cat hostname
sauron
[root@gandalf etc]#
```

Im unable to reboot this server anytime soon and some of my team is mixing up the server due to the hostname showing an older system name. Simply put: need prompt to show `[user@sauron dir]#` instead of `[user@gandalf dir]#`.

Google'd around for this but wasn't able to see a way to do this without the reboot. Thanks for your consideration!

Comment: Logout and login should work to update this variable. See my answer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to do this using the `hostname` command:

```
hostname -F /etc/hostname
```

After this change, the previous hostname will still show at your current prompt.  To see the change without rebooting, enter a new shell.  If you are using `bash`, type:

```
bash
```

Your new `hostname` should now be displayed.

Comment: The question refers to reloading the `/etc/hostname` file, not modifying the hostname via argument.

Comment: @marc there is no way to "reload hosname" like using `source` command. the user will have to point to `/etc/hostname` as argument of `hostname` command: `hostname -F /etc/hostname`. There is no magic on changing hostname. Unfortunately to update this at shell prompts, users will have to logout and login again...

Comment: @nwildner as far as I know there is no logout and login, and following the source code of hostname GNU which uses `sethostname` and which doesn't implies any such action. (the `http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sethostname.2.html`)

Comment: @marc Not my answer =). I know hostname change will not require a logout+login, but updating this information at the user prompt will require a reload on `/etc/profile`. Take a look at this file and you will find where `HOSTNAME` variable is feed with hostname information during login. This is why its better to logout+login everyone connected to that host... There is no easy way to update everyone's `HOSTNAME` shell variable...

Comment: take a look at MY answer ;)

Comment: If you can't even logout and login for whatever reason ```exec -l bash``` does the trick without wasting a process.

Answer (score 0):

Restart of network service is not required. You can follow any of the below procedure.

```
hostnamectl set-hostname "new.host.name"
```

Logout and login the system

OR

```
hostname "new.host.name"
```

Logout and Login to the system

OR

```
echo "new.host.name" > /proc/sys/kernel/hostname
```

Logout and login the system

But make sure `HOSTNAME` is set in `/etc/sysconfig/network` file otherwise it cannot assign hostname during system reboot.

Comment: The question refers to reloading the `/etc/hostname` file, not modifying the hostname via argument.

Comment: This will not update `PS1` shell variable neither `HOSTNAME` profile variable on-the-fly

Answer (score 0):

With `hostname` (busybox & GNU) and editing the desired hostname in `/etc/hostname`:

```
hostname -F /etc/hostname
```

Comment: This will not update `PS1` shell variable neither `HOSTNAME` profile variable on-the-fly

Comment: @nwildner read the question carefully!!! The questioner states: "but im still showing the old hostname at prompt" and also refers to the `/etc/hostname` files. Sorry mate.

Comment: Showing at prompt, and "showing in a command return" is not the same thing. Look at the rest of que question that makes anyone believe that this is just a matter of updating `PS1` and `HOSTNAME` on bash: "need prompt to show [user@sauron dir]# instead of [user@gandalf dir]#.". He already changed `/etc/hostname` if you take a look at his `cat` command, but the prompt will not be updated for the reasons that i have explained at my answer(that got downvoted without even a comment...)... So, editing `/etc/hostname` or changing on the fly with `hostname sauron` will not update the USER PROMPT..

Comment: I've tested my answer in an angstrom box and worked flawlessly! And as a matter of fact my answer got also downvoted as well!

Comment: Ahw, i see. You are not using CentOS7 the same way as the question, what makes your answer somehow not valid ;)

Comment: I'm cool  :) Just taking the joke to a next level, of course